# How to prevent modal click-through?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, event-bubbling

I have a modal that looks something like this:

```
<div className="modal modal-focuser" tabindex="1" style="z-index: 5;">
  <div className="handle-modal-close"></div>
  <div className="modal-content modal-content">
    <div className="body">
      <span>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="title-text">Title Text</div>
          <div className="body-text">Body Text</div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleView} className="toggle-view">Switch View</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the click code like the following:

```
toggleView = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();

  this.setState(prevState => ({ view: !prevState.view}));
}
```

But for some reason (despite the stop propagation), when I click the button, sometimes the parent's event handlers are still being activated.

That is, there is a table behind the modal with click-able rows, and when I click the Toggle button in the modal, not only is that button clicked, but *also* the table row behind the behind (which also has its own click event handlers)

The stranger thing is that this only sometimes happens, and only happens on mobile. Try as I might, I can't replicate the behavior on my PC in Chrome or Firefox.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're using the `onclick` handler, which essentially ignores all the propegation through down-up events. Try using `onmousedown`. Chances are the thing underneath the modal has a down or up event. Learn about "bubbling" : [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

```
<button onMouseDown={this.toggleView} ... yada yada
```

Using the mousedown will allow you to prevent bubbling through the `stopPropegation`, and maybe also look into `stopImmediatePropegation` -- which prevents other listeners of the same type (click, down, up) from getting called: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation